# Using Ajax on JqueryDate Changed, force reload of form collection inside BeginForm

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

My Razor `PendingBillsByWeekView` has a Form/Model with a - `DatePicker (m => m.date)` & `Table data`.

From inside the From Model collection, when the datepickers date is changed,

1. **How can I reload the form bills data for that date**?
2. Is an AJAX button or link inside `BeginForm` THE CORRECT WAY? or do I *need* to use `Ajax.BeginForm`?
   I also want the new date to be set in the datepicker.

---

```
@model Models.BillsModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
//@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 <h3>Bills Table, please select Date Below</h3>
 <div id="dates">
    //Is label Correct or should I use Input/TextBox??
    // HOW to submit this data change as AJAX and Reload the Form?
    <label id="DATEPICKER_BILLS">Bills Date: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate)</label>
 </div >
 <div id="TaBle_Bills">
    // Table Bills records I want to reload, how to refresh this form
 </div >

<input type="submit" class="btn blue" name="ReviewedBillsButton" value="Save Draft" />
 }
```

---

Is this return correct to reload the form?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateDateFilters(DateTime dateStart, DateTime dateEnd = null)
{
   if (dateEnd == null) dateEnd = dateStart.AddDays(2);
   if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
       {
         return PartialView( "_Partial", bModel );
       }
   else
   {         
        DateTime start = DateTime.ParseExact(dateStart.Substring(0,10), "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        DateTime end = DateTime.ParseExact(dateEnd.Substring(0, 10), "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        BillsModel bModel = BillFilterd(start, end);
        return View(bModel); // 
    }
  }

 [HttpPost] //Save on Submit
 public ActionResult PendingBillsByWeekView(BillsModel model)
 {
  // the startdate never makes it back!
 }
```

---

How to Ajax the date picker to reload new bills for each date selected.
EDITED - credit @stephen

```
$("StartDate").change(function() {
       var dateVal = $("StartDate").val()
       $.ajax({
           url: "/home/UpdateDateFilters",
           type: "get" // or POST?
           data:  dateVal  //$this.val()
       }).done(function(data) {
           alert(data);
           // not working, how do I remove old and attach new?
           $("#TaBle_Bills").html(data);
       }).fail(function() {
           alert('error');
       });
   });
```

---

Added Model

```
// this class creates an Invoice based on the selected range of dates.
public class BillsModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required] // Date for the bills on that date
    public DateTime Date { get; set; } 

    [Required] // From StartDate
    public DateTime SelectedStartDate { get; set; } 


    [Required] // To EndDate, if this is not set, only bills for that date
    public DateTime? SelectedEndDate { get; set; } 

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Review is required")]
    [StringLength(4000)]
    public string ReviewNotes { get; set; }

    public int ClientInvoiceId { get; set; }

    //Table with list of records Bills
    public virtual List<Bill> Bills { get; set; }

    public decimal? TotalCost { get; set; }
}

public class Bill
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime BillDate { get; set; } // Date of bill  

    [StringLength(40)]
    public string InvoiceItem { get; set; }

    public decimal? Cost { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: To handle the change event of your form control, its `$('#StartDate').change(function() {` - your `EditorFor()` method generates `id="StartDate"` and it can be a GET or a POST, but your not passing any values for the parameters `dateStart` and `dateEnd`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I made the change and its still not refreshing the form. I dont need both start and end, I can remove the end date for simplicity

Comment: It needs to be `data: { dateStart: dateVal }` and that parameter will be bound to the value of your form control. And since you have marked the method with `[HttpPost]`, then use `type: "post"`

Comment: You have also not shown what `bModel` is or where you declared it. If you still having problems, then advise what errors you getting in the browser console.

Comment: @StephenMuecke my model code is added. The model is for collection of table bills based on the day (or day range). The master invoice/bill by default holds 1 days bills, but could also span upto the endDate bills. I use the main date, unless user selects a range, then I copy the`startDate` to `Date`, and use the `EndDate` and add filter between start date and end date

Comment: Did you change it to `data: { dateStart: dateVal }` and `type: "post"`? But its still not clear what your problem is. In the POST method you will enter the `if` block and the only code there is `return PartialView( "_Partial", bModel );` and nowhere have you shown where you initialize `bModel` or set its properties

Answer (score 1):

first i prefer to use `GET` since you are only getting the data so your ajax call will be like this

```
   $("#StartDate").change(function () {
                var dateVal = $("#StartDate").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/home/UpdateDateFilters",
                    type: "get" ,
                    data:  {dateStart : dateVal,dateEnd:null}  
            }).done(function(data) {
                alert(data);
                $("#TaBle_Bills").html(data);
            }).fail(function() {
                alert('error');
            });
            });
```

note in `jquery` we use `#` to get data of specific id and in action

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult UpdateDateFilters(DateTime dateStart, DateTime? dateEnd)
{  

}
```

you cannot set dateEnd to null so we use `nullable ?` it will set the default value to `null`